# React Multipage NavBar reseting its state

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

Trying to set up a simple NavBar using react-bootstrap, I want to maintain in the state the active page, this is the component:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
    
    const Navigation = () => {
        const [activeItem, setActivePage] = useState("initial");
        return (
            <>
                <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/page1">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Nav activeKey={activeItem} onSelect={(e) => setActivePage(e)} className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link eventKey="/page1"  href="/page1">Page 1</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey="/page2"  href="/page2">Page 2</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <p>current: {activeItem}</p>
                </Navbar>
            </>
        )
    }
    export default Navigation;
```

And this is the main App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

import Page1 from './routes/Page1';
import Page2 from './routes/Page2';

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Router>
       <Navigation/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
          <Route  path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

The issue I have is that the `activeItem` state variable gets reset every time a page loads.  So `activeItem` is `"initial"` at the very beginning, when I click on a page it briefly changes to the proper `eventKey` but then immediately returns to `"initial"` when the page loads so the state is not preserved across page loads, but reset every time.

I'm new to react, already tried going to other posts and react-bootstrap documentation.  If I change the href values to stay in the same page (e.g. by making href="#explora") everything works as intended.

What am I missing here to make react keep state in the NavBar across page routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check into the location object using the `useLocation` hook, the `pathname` property which contains the path for the current page and also with this approach you don't need to save the current page in any state. So, having said that your `Navigation` component it should look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Navigation = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/page1">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav activeKey={location.pathname} className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="/page1">Page 1</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/page2">Page 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <p>current: {location.pathname}</p>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Tx, does not work throws: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Comment: Maybe you have some conflicts with your packages versions. Here is a guide that can help you https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: 1) Checked react-dom version is OK (17.0)  2) Breaking rules, not sure how to check if the proposed solution meets the rules, though seems fine  3) React is not duplicated

Comment: Finally got it, I reinstalled react-router-dom and now is working, thanks  a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the `const [activeItem, setActivePage] = useState("initial");` into App.js file?

App.js :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

import Page1 from './routes/Page1';
import Page2 from './routes/Page2';

const App = () => (
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState('initial');
  
  <>
    <Router>
       <Navigation 
        activeItem={activeItem} 
        setActiveItem={setActiveItem}
       />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
          <Route  path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

Navigation component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Navigation = ({ activeItem, setActivePage }) => {
  return (
      <>
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/page1">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav activeKey={activeItem} onSelect={(e) => setActivePage(e)} className="mr-auto">
                <Nav.Link eventKey="/page1"  href="/page1">Page 1</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="/page2"  href="/page2">Page 2</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <p>current: {activeItem}</p>
        </Navbar>
      </>
  )
}
export default Navigation;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the behavior is the same, state is restored to default when a page loads.